# Show notification(blink tab) when a new message arrives

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am not sure whether the code is correct or not. As i mentioned in the title, the idea is to **blink the browser tab if it is not in focus** when a new message arrives. The given code(without `$("#full_chat").bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function()`),does the work but it always blinks once the focus is lost. Please suggest a way to fix the issue.

```
<script>
setInterval(function refreshPage() { 

         var user=$("#head").text();

         $.post("retrieve.php",
                {                 
                    user:user
              },
              function(data,status){

                        $("#full_chat").append("<span class='you'>"+data+"</span>");
                        $('#full_chat').emoticonize();

                    $(window).blur(function() { //I want the notofication to show only when the tab has no focus

                         $("#full_chat").bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){//The notification should appear only when a message comes

        //Code for showing "New chat message!" using 'jquery.titlealert.js'

                        $.titleAlert("New chat message!", {
                        requireBlur:false,
                            stopOnFocus:true,
                            interval:700
                            });
                        });

                    });

              });

         }, 1500);
<script>
```

**'retrieve.php' file content**

```
   <?php session_start();
    $other_user=$_POST['user'];
    //$flag=$_POST['flag'];
    include_once('db.php');
    $uname=$_SESSION['username'];

    //date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');


        $q="select message,sender,time from chat where username='$uname' and delivered=0  and      sender='$other_user' order by time ASC";
        $qe = mysqli_query($con,$q);
        $q1="UPDATE chat SET delivered=1  WHERE username='$uname' and sender='$other_user'" ;
        $qe1 = mysqli_query($con,$q1);
        while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($qe)) {
            echo "(".$r['time'].")  ". $r['sender'].": ".$r['message']."<br>";

        }
         mysqli_close($con); 
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my code a little and now its working perfectly :)

**retrieve.php**

```
<?php session_start();
    $other_user=$_POST['user'];
    $flag=$_POST['flag'];
    include_once('db.php');
    $uname=$_SESSION['username'];

    //date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');


    $q="select message,sender,time from chat where username='$uname' and delivered=0  and sender='$other_user' order by time ASC";
    $qe = mysqli_query($con,$q);
    $q1="UPDATE chat SET delivered=1  WHERE username='$uname' and sender='$other_user'" ;
    $qe1 = mysqli_query($con,$q1);
    if($r=mysqli_fetch_array($qe)) {
            echo "(".$r['time'].")  ". $r['sender'].": ".$r['message']."<br>";
    //modification: added an else statement("echo failed") for later use.
    }else {           
        echo "failed";  
    }
     mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
    setInterval(function refreshPage() { 

                 var user=$("#head").text();
                 $.post("retrieve.php",
                        {                 
                            user:user
                      },
                      function(data,status){
                                if($.trim(data)!="failed"){ //if not "failed" to execute query
                                        $("#full_chat").append("<span class='you'>"+data+"</span>");
                                        $('#full_chat').emoticonize();
                                        window.onblur = function () {  //**if window has no focu**s
                                                $('#full_chat').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){  //**if any change happened to the div**
                                                    $.titleAlert("New Message!", { //**display notification**
                                                    requireBlur:true,                                               
                                                    stopOnFocus:true,
                                                    //duration:10000,                                               
                                                    //interval:500
                                                });
                                                });


                                    }
                                }
                    }); }, 1500);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

please escape your `variables` that are passed to mysql and prevent sql injections. if you are working with javascript + php use the `json` format to pass data between them.

jquery support ajax request in json but you need to switch to the `$.ajax` function in jquery.

**retrieve.php**

```
include_once('db.php');

//$flag     =   $_POST['flag'];
$returnData =   [];
$other_user =   mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user']);
$uname      =   mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['username']);

$queryMessages  = "select message,sender,time from chat where username='".$uname."' and delivered=0  and sender='".$other_user."' order by time ASC";
$resultMessages = mysqli_query($con, $queryMessages);

if( mysqli_num_rows($resultMessages) >= 1 )
    {
        while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($resultMessages)) {
            $returnData[] = "(" . $r['time'] . ")  " . $r['sender'] . ": " . $r['message'] . "<br>";
        }
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE chat SET delivered=1  WHERE username='".$uname."' and sender='".$other_user."'");
}

mysqli_close($con);

echo json_encode($returnData);
```

**javascript side**

```
setInterval(function refreshPage() {
    var userData = $("#head").text();
    $.ajax({
        url : 'retrieve.php',
        type : "POST",
        data : {
            user : userData
        },
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function (messages) {
            if( messages.length >= 1 )
            {
                $.each(messages, function(index) {
                    $("#full_chat").append("<span class='you'>" + messages[index] + "</span>");
                });

                $('#full_chat').emoticonize();
                $.titleAlert("New chat message!", {
                    requireBlur : true,
                    stopOnFocus : true,
                    interval : 700
                });
            }
        }
    });
}, 1500);
```

---

what is the problem with the `titleAlert` plugin. it has all functionalty buil-in. this works fine for me.

just set the option `requireBlur` to `true`

> If true, the call will be ignored unless the window is out of focus.
>   Known issues: Firefox doesn't recognize tab switching as blur, and
>   there are some minor IE problems as well.

Comment: you need to check if the ``data`` variable has data if so fire the ``titleAlert`` something like this (it depends on what data your ``receive.php`` returns) ... ``if(data) { $.titleAlert... }``

Comment: did that too.. still not working.. i ll update 'retrieve.php' file contents in the qstn nw.

Comment: yep please show us the response from your ``retrieve.php`` when no message is present

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58422/discussion-between-ins0-and-arshad-muhammed).